# Monitoring ReplicatedMap on Management center?

Tags: hazelcast

There are tabs for `Map`, `List`, `Queue`, `Executors` etc in the left navigation pane of Management center.

But, I don't see any tab for `ReplicatedMap`. Is there a way I can query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're working on adding `RelpicatedMap` view to the Management Center (No ETA at this point though). Meanwhile, you can use `Scripts` view to query replicated map using JavaScript or Groovy.